# Priority scheduling algorithm using std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning priority scheduling algorithm and trying to implement it using `std::vector`. But the current performance of my code that's partially implemented is not that good since I'm performing `sort` operation every time I add a new process to `std::vector` list. Can somebody suggest ways I can improve my current partially implemented algorithm. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

void print_list(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list) {
    for (const auto& pa : pair_list)
        std::cout << "process_ID: " << pa.first << ", " << "priority: " << pa.second << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void add_pro(int pro_ID, int pro_pri, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list) {
    pair_list.emplace_back(pro_ID, pro_pri);

    std::sort(pair_list.begin(), pair_list.end(), [=](std::pair<int, int>& a, std::pair<int, int>& b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    });
}

bool check_pro_is_present(int pro_ID, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list) {
    for (const auto& pa : pair_list) {
        if (pa.first == pro_ID)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool is_higher_pri_pro_present(int pro_ID, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list) {
    if (pair_list.front().first == pro_ID)
        return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> process_ID_list { 1345, 45, 5646, 52525, 55757, 23424, 68696, 55878, 667, 252 };
    std::vector<int> process_pri_list { 41, 334, 747, 41, 47, 7, 75, 544, 42, 6 };
    
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pair_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < process_ID_list.size(); ++i) {
        int new_pro_ID = process_ID_list.at(i);
        int new_pro_pri = process_pri_list.at(i);

        if (!check_pro_is_present(new_pro_ID, pair_list))
            add_pro(new_pro_ID, new_pro_pri, pair_list);
        else
            std::cout << "process is already in list" << std::endl;

        print_list(pair_list);
    }

    int query_pro_ID = 1345;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_higher_pri_pro_present(query_pro_ID, pair_list) << std::endl;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: One sound choice here is a priority queue, such as [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Actually I thought of using it, but the problem is I can't iterate through the list(without popping or copying) if I want to say print current list data and to remove any process from the list based on process identifier due to some reasons, if I implement using `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: In that case, perhaps a `vector` with `make_heap`, `pop_heap` (etc.) will be more amenable to your needs.

Comment: @JerryCoffin what about `std::set`?. Do you think it has better performance over `std::vector` in this case scenario?

Comment: Harder to guess about set. With `set`, each node is dynamically allocated, so a lot here depends on how fast the allocator is (but it's probably at least worth a try).

Comment: @Jerry, would you consider writing an answer that describes the pros and cons of the possible alternative types that could be used?  I would, but I have other things that need doing today...

Answer (score 1):

While comments have suggested more suitable types than `std::vector`, I'm going to assume that the use of this underlying type is a given, and suggest straightforward improvements without changing that.

The main performance concern is here:

> ```
> void add_pro(int pro_ID, int pro_pri, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list) {
>     pair_list.emplace_back(pro_ID, pro_pri);
>
>     std::sort(pair_list.begin(), pair_list.end(), [=](std::pair<int, int>& a, std::pair<int, int>& b) {
>         return a.second < b.second;
>     });
> }
> ```

It's wasteful to sort the vector every time we add an element, when we know it was sorted before we called this function.  Instead, we need to *insert* the new element in the correct position.

```
void add_pro(int pro_ID, int pro_pri, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list)
{
    auto position = std::upper_bound(pair_list.begin(), pair_list.end(), pro_pri,
                                     [](auto pri, auto const& ele) { return pri < ele.second; });
    pair_list.emplace(position, pro_ID, pro_pri);
}
```

---

We use the type `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` a lot.  It's worth giving it a name:

```
using priority_queue = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;
```

That makes changing the code easier, e.g. if we decide that process ids actually need to be `unsigned long` or something.

However, I observe that *every* function takes one of these as an argument.  That suggests that we want a class with this vector as member, then convert those free functions to be members of that class.

---

Thank you for including the test program - that's always helpful in a review.  There's a couple of small points:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < process_ID_list.size(); ++i) {
> ```

We're mixing signed and unsigned types in this comparison (`int` and `std::size_t`).  Obviously we should change `int i` to `std::size_t i` - and enable more compiler warnings.

> ```
>        std::cout << "process is already in list" << std::endl;
> ```

Prefer to use `std::cerr` for error messages.

---

The pattern `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can simply be replaced with `return condition`.  So:

```
bool is_higher_pri_pro_present(int pro_ID, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list)
{
    return pair_list.front().first != pro_ID;
}
```

---

The loop in `check_pro_is_present` can be replaced with `std::any_of`:

```
bool check_pro_is_present(int pro_ID, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& pair_list)
{
    return std::any_of(pair_list.begin(), pair_list.end(),
                       [pro_ID](auto const& e){ return e.first == pro_ID; });
}
```

---

## Modified code

This is just a beginning - we'll probably want an initialiser-list constructor, and replace `print()` with `operator<<()`, but it's a start.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename Priority = int>
class priority_queue
{
    std::vector<std::pair<T, Priority>> values = {};

public:
    void print(std::ostream &os) const {
        for (const auto& pa : values) {
            os << "process_ID: " << pa.first << ", "
               << "priority: " << pa.second << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    void add(T t, Priority pri) {
        auto const position
            = std::upper_bound(values.begin(), values.end(),
                               pri,
                               [](auto const& pri, auto const& ele) { return pri < ele.second; });
        values.emplace(position, std::move(t), std::move(pri));
    }

    bool contains(int pro_ID) const
    {
        return std::any_of(values.begin(), values.end(),
                           [pro_ID](auto const& e){ return e.first == pro_ID; });
    }

    bool has_higher(int pro_ID) const
    {
        return values.front().first != pro_ID;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::pair<int,int> processes[]
        = { { 1345, 41 }, { 45, 334 }, { 5646, 747 },
            { 52525, 41 }, { 55757, 47 },
            { 23424, 7 }, { 68696, 75 }, { 55878, 544 },
            { 667, 42 }, { 252, 6 } };

    priority_queue<int, int> queue;
    for (auto const& p: processes) {
        if (queue.contains(p.first)) {
            std::cerr << p.first << " is already in list\n";
        } else {
            queue.add(p.first, p.second);
        }
        queue.print(std::cout);
    }

    int query_pro_ID = 1345;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << queue.has_higher(query_pro_ID) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Well if you think that this can be better implemented other than using `std::vector`, please let me know.

Comment: I might write a separate answer for that, if I get time.  Or perhaps somebody else will?

Comment: @TobySpeight, I can do that next week, although it might take time until Friday or so. I will ping you here if you’re interested in the results.